# Loading data while entering root state

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to load data or perform some calculations while the application enters the root state, any ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what's your problem, because controllers does not have states, so I guess here you're talking about routes.

If you wants to load data when entering in the root state, the feature is not implemented yet, but will probably be later.

Take a look at this issue: [Controller instances not available in connectOutlets of root state.](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/941), I think this is exactly your problem.

Before they implement this feature, you could still:

- Load data in the `ApplicationController#init` method
- Add a route which contains all others (root.all), and load data in the `connectOutlets` method of the `all` routes (I don't like this solution)
- Observes the `applicationController` property of the router by doing this (see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu6R3/)):

  ```
  App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    loadData: function() {
      // load data here
    }.observes('applicationController'),
  });
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry I did not ask properly but that is what I mean "loading data while entering root state"

Comment: But don't you think adding an observer on applicationController significantly slows down the application ?

Comment: I don't think so, because its *should* just be triggered when the `router.applicationController` changes. Consequently, it should be called only once. (but I'm not 100% sure of how the router works)

Comment: It's a doubt I'm not sure I'm right or wrong but if any property inside applicationController changes doesn't that fire the observer ?

Comment: No, it fires the observer only when the `router.applicationController` changes, as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zG8gs/